# Guardar Valor anterior de un campo y el Valor actual de un Campo (Histórico de Modificaciones) - Codeingniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

quisiera saber si me podrías echar una mano con un punto que llevo atascado unos días. El caso es que quiere que la aplicación la cual estoy mejorando tenga un historial de cambios, es decir, si en el campo nombre antes estaba "Pepe" y se cambia por "Pepe 2" en una tabla (la cual ya la tengo creada) me guarde la persona que lo modifico, la fecha, hora y los campos Valor anterior y Valor Actual

[image: tabla de historial de cambios]

Cada vez que en la aplicación se haga un cambio en esta pestaña :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debe guardar en esta otra la fecha, nombre de usuario y de la persona la cual se ha modificado y los cambios que se realizo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La aplicación está desarrollada en php con el Framework de Codeigniter,si tenéis alguna idea , sera bien recibida.

Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Lo que tendrías que hacer es antes de hacer el **update**, hacer un **insert** en la tabla que has creado para que haga de **log**, extrayendo el campo "valor anterior" de la tabla antes de sufrir el update y el "valor actual" de lo que estás recibiendo desde la vista. Sin mostrar código y lo que llevas hecho me temo que no se te puede dar una respuesta más concreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre vas a mostrar el histórico de datetimes y el historial de modificaciones para "Nombre" y "Apellidos" te recomiendo entonces mejor crear una nueva tabla con el histórico de cambios y que allí se alojen dichos cambios, sólo necesitarás un FK.

Cada que se modifiquen esos Datos Generales tomas su id y agregas un nuevo row al histórico.